# Solr document Scoring/Boosting not working as expected

Tags: solrnet

We have integrated solr search with .net project, but we are facing some issues related to document boosting or scoring feature of solr.

**Problem:** Solr is not returning score as per term frequency in document.

**Eg:-** We have created four documents whose Title contain term "Link" and solr has returned score as below:

```
1)Link ==> 6.037953
2)Link Link Link Link Link ==> 5.9249415
3)Link Link ==> 5.374235
4)Link Link Link ==> 5.2746024
```

Can anyone please help me on solr scoring or boosting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Scoring calculation for Solr is something really complex. Here, you have to begin with [the primal equation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html):

> score(q,d)   =   coord(q,d)  ·  queryNorm(q)  ·   ∑   ( tf(t in d)  · 
>   idf(t)2  ·  t.getBoost() ·  norm(t,d) )

You have `tf` parameter which represents term frequency and its value is the squareroot of the frequency of the term.

You also have `norm` (aka `fieldNorm`)  which is used in `fieldWeight` calculation. Let's take your example:

> Link Link Link Link Link

Your score will be calculate like (you can see this by adding [`debugQuery`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debugQuery) parameter):

```
5.9249415 = fieldWeight, product of:
  2.236068 = tf(freq=5.0), with freq of:
    5.0 = termFreq=5.0
  idf (wich will be the same for all your scores)
  0.4375 = fieldNorm(doc=177)
```

> link

```
6.037953= fieldWeight, product of:
  1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
    1.0 = termFreq=1.0
  idf (wich will be the same for all your scores)
  1.0 = fieldNorm
```

Here, `link` has a better score than the other because `fieldWeight` is the product of `tf`, `idf` and `fieldNorm`. This last one is higher for `link` document because he only contains one term.

As above documentation said:

> lengthNorm - computed when the document is added to the index in
>   accordance with the number of tokens of this field in the document, so
>   that shorter fields contribute more to the score.

The more terms you have in a field, lower `fieldNorm` will be. 
*Be careful with the [value of this field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054250/solr-scoring-fieldnorm/27644148#27644148).*

So, to conclude, here you have a perfect mix to understand that the score is not calculated only with the frequency but also with the number of term that you have in your field.

Comment: Do you have any idea on How to retrieve word frequency on multiple words in solr 5.2.1 . e.g using termfreq(Field, 'searchterm') function I get frequency for exact match only. but not for each word inside single quote.

Comment: Thanks for help, but my concern is solr returns score which is confusing, see for  2)Link Link Link Link Link ==> 5.9249415 score which should be lowest compare to others.Do you have any idea on How to retrieve word frequency on multiple words in solr 5.2.1 . e.g using termfreq(Field, 'searchterm') function I get frequency for exact match only. but not for each word inside single quote.

Comment: As I said, for `Link Link Link Link Link`, you have a lower `fieldNorm` but a higher `tf`, so to have the order, you have to make a mix between these 2 coefficients !

Comment: For the other question, I don't think it is possible without create yourself a custom function